# Why did John Doe appear as press photographer?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, se7en

John tried to face the detectives and tried to take photos of them in Se7en movie.

[image]

What is the reason?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### We don't know...exactly.

However, it's not unknown, at least in movies, for serial killers to get close to, or [insert themselves into the investigation](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DetectiveMole).

Here John Doe **disguises himself** as a press photographer, perhaps to see how the police are carrying out the investigation....or perhaps because he needed a disguise to exit the building where the *Sloth* victim was being held.

Also, using the flash makes it harder for the detectives to get a good look at his face.

In fact, the [script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/seven_production.html) offers more clues in that it was intended to show that John Doe **was** following the investigation. Only the final part seems to have made it into the movie...

> ```
>     On the walls, more pictures: of the crime scenes, but from the
>     outside looking in.  Long shots.  Police cars.  Ambulances.
>     Uniformed officers putting up police barrier ribbons outside
>     buildings.  The coroner's wagon.
>
>     Somerset stares at them, taking them in, realizing...
>
>                              MILLS
>               We had him and we let him go.
>
>     In the backgrounds of the pictures: Somerset and Mills.  In
>     another: Mills crossing the street.  In another: Somerset and
>     Mills getting out of Somerset's car.
>
>     One photo, close shot, shows Mills and Somerset on the stairwell
>     of the building where Victor's body was found.  It is the
>     picture taken by the balding, almost silly looking reporter.
> ```

[image]

Comment: I liked ur answer. Maybe he came their to check the condition of him or else to just photograph the detectives. That is the reason, he recognizes and shoots them